# Whats the different between scanf() and to initialize an Integer directly? in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a code and I'm wondering what the difference between scanf() and to initialize an integer directly is. 
When I compile this code :

```
for(u=0;u<reihen;u++){                          
   fgets(a,MAX,stdin);
   k = strlen(a)-1;
   printf("Value of k: %d\n",k);
   for(z=0;z<k;z++){
   }
}
printf("hello");
}
```

with this initialization of "reihen"

```
scanf("%d",&reihen);
```

the code skips the `fgets(a,MAX,stdin);` and the rest of the code except for `k = strlen(a)-1;` and `printf("Value of k: %d\n",k);` but just for the first circuit. Then the code works fine.

and when I'm initialize the `reihen` directly like `reihen = 2;`
It doesn't skip anything.

Could someone explain me this please ?

Comment: (not just a newline - `scanf` stops at *any* whitespace)

Comment: and why does fgets() reads this Newline ? @user3121023

Comment: So  scanf()'s buffer is "6\n" after getting input of 6 am i right ? And if this is right, why does fgets() gets this newline ? Its still in the buffer of scanf() isnt it ? @user3121023

Comment: @user3121023, you should formulate an answer based on the comments. Together, they answer the OP's question very well.